# Hibernate OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT increase field with @Version by 2 instead of 1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got sample object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SAMPLE_AGGREGATES")
public class SampleAggregate {
    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false)
    private String value;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private SampleEntity child;

    @Version
    private Long version;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    // getters, setters and constructor
}
```

I would like at the moment when I change something in child, the parent's version changes, so I add OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT to save method in repository:

```
    public void save(final T aggregate) {
        if (!this.entityManager.contains(aggregate)) {
            this.entityManager.persist(aggregate);
        }
        this.entityManager.lock(aggregate, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT);
    }
```

Now when I change something in child, parent version is updated, but when I change parent, version is updated twice (there are two updates in log: one with changed data & version and one with changed only version). Problem is of course in OPTIMISTIC_FORCE_INCREMENT, if I remove it, everything works good.

Is there any way for the version to update only once when I change parent (and of course, when I change child, parent's version is updated)?

Comment: golden shovel I win... did you mange to figure out the underlying issue?

Comment: No, but I wasn't really looking for a solution after writing this question on SO - it's just one additional query to database and it does not affect our application flow.